# upload multiple selected file on android mobile in php code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to upload multiple file with select file on Android Mobile but i can not select with particular multiple file, i used `multiple-form/data` and

`multiple="multiple"` properties of text fields in **PHP**

Comment: i am trying to upload multiple files on android mobile with select option but i am not able to upload files

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
```